# HibernateSystemException: Unable to resolve entity name from Class [java.lang.Long] in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm, criteria

I'm trying to execute following query using `Model.executeQuery` in Grails 2.4.3 with Hibernate 3 plugin where `Model` is my domain class extending `CatalogueElement` (with `tablePerHierarchy false` set):

```
select count(m)
from Model as m
where m.status = :status
    and m not in (select r1.destination from Relationship r1 where r1.relationshipType = :type)
    and m in (select r2.destination from Relationship r2 where r2.relationshipType = :classificationType and r2.source in :classifications)
```

When I execute it I got following exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Unable to resolve entity name from Class [java.lang.Long] expected instance/subclass of [org.modelcatalogue.core.CatalogueElement]; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve entity name from Class [java.lang.Long] expected instance/subclass of [org.modelcatalogue.core.CatalogueElement]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:708)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:414)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:416)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeFind(HibernateTemplate.java:348)
```

The domain classes looks similar to:

```
class CatalogueElement { String name }
class Model extends CatalogueElement { ... }
class Relationship {
    CatalogueElement source
    CatalogueElement destination
}
```

The problem is obviously caused by subquery statements as if I skip them everything works well. Actually I got similar errors when using subquery with `DetachedCriteria`. Does anyone have a solution for this? I don't want to fetch the subquery first and pass the results to the parameters as it could end up in thousands of records.

Comment: It would be helpful to see simplified versions of your domain classes

Comment: I've added the domain classes and also the answer as I've figured out that the problem was quite stupid but there is a chance that someone else will be as stupid as me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was in the `:classifications` named argument which was set of `Long` ids not set of `CatalogueElement` entities. The proper query is

```
select count(m)
from Model as m
where m.status = :status
    and m not in (select r1.destination from Relationship r1 where r1.relationshipType = :type)
    and m in (select r2.destination from Relationship r2 where r2.relationshipType = :classificationType and r2.source.id in :classifications)
```